# Escaping Custom Operators in R

Tags: r, operators, binary-operators

One may define a [new binary operator](https://cran.r-project.org/doc/manuals/r-release/R-intro.html#Defining-new-binary-operators)...

```r
`%my_op%` <- function(lhs, rhs) {
  # ...
}
```

...and use it like so:

```r
4 %my_op% 5
```

Experimentation shows that *nearly* any sequence of characters is valid, between the opening `%` "bookends".  The definition need only escape (`\`) the backtick (`` ` ``) used for complex [`name`](https://rdrr.io/r/base/name.html)s, along with the escape character (`\`) itself:

```r
`%space op%` <- sum
`%tick\`op%` <- sum
`%slash\\op%` <- sum
```

When the operators are actually used, the escape sequence is unnecessary, thanks (apparently) to the syntactic significance of the `%` bookends.

```r
4 %space op% 5
#> [1] 9

4 %tick`op% 5
#> [1] 9

4 %slash\op% 5
#> [1] 9
```

## Problem

Is it possible to include the `%` character *itself* in the operator name?  I have tried several approaches to define such an operator..

```r
# No escape.
`%test%op%` <- sum

# Conventional escape (by backslash).
`%test\%op%` <- sum
#> Error: '\%' is an unrecognized escape in character string starting "`%test\%"

# Conventional escape (by escaped backslash)..
`%test\\%op%` <- sum

# Reflexive escape (by doubling).
`%test%%op%` <- sum
```

...but they are syntactically unviable:

```r
4 %test%op% 5
#> Error: unexpected input in "4 %test%op% 5"

4 %test\%op% 5
#> Error: unexpected input in "4 %test\%op% 5"

4 %test%%op% 5
#> Error: unexpected SPECIAL in "4 %test%%op%"
```

## Questions

1. Is there any way (ie. escape sequence) to define an operator with `%` in its name?  If so, how would one *call* this operator when using it?
2. What complex names (`` `...\`...\\...` ``) are valid for R variables but *not* for custom operators?  And vice versa?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is no problem in *defining* a binary function with an extra `%` in it:

```r
`%my % func%` <- function(a, b) paste0(round(100 * a / b, 3), '%')
```

But we cannot call it using the special binary operator syntax:

```r
5 %my % func% 10
#> Error: unexpected input in "5 %my % func% 10"
```

We would have to call it like any other normal function:

```r
`%my % func%`(5, 10)
#> [1] "50%"
```

The reason is that when the R parser tokenizes input, it goes into a special state when it comes across a `%` that hasn't been escaped by a backtick, reading the tokens until it comes across the very next `%`, and reading the characters in between literally. Backticks, quotes, backslashes etc makes no difference to how the second `%` is interpreted by the parser.

In fact, we can even have a binary function with all these symbols in it (it's easier to define this using `assign`

```r
assign('% `"@\\ %', function(a, b) paste0(round(100 * a / b, 3), '%'))
```

Which allows the rather bizarre but legal R code:

```r
5 % `"@\ % 10
#> [1] "50%"
```

There *are* ways to have something that *looks like* a binary operator with a `%` in it if you get creative with non-standard evaluation:

```r
`%_%` <- function(a, b) {
  if(deparse(as.call(substitute(a))[[1]]) == "%_%")
    paste0(round(100 * as.call(substitute(a))[[2]]/b, 3), "%")
}
```

Which allows:

```
1 %_%percent%_% 2
#> [1] "50%"
```

But this is really just two binary operators strung together and ignoring the symbol in between. You can't use a special binary operator *as* a special binary operator with a single `%` in it.

Comment: Thanks for the in-depth answer!  Also, I just realized now that one may define complex variables simply by using string literals: `'% \`"@\\ %' <- function(a, b){...}`.  No `assign()` needed!

Answer (score 3):

From 10.3.4 in the language definition : https://cran.r-project.org/doc/manuals/R-lang.pdf

> R allows user-defined infix operators. They have the form of a string of characters delimited by the '%' character. The string can contain any printable character except '%'. The escape sequences for strings do not apply here.

So no, you can't use `%` in the middle of an infix op